# Authentication for Google Custom Search Api

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search, google-search-api, google-oauth

**Short question:**

Does anyone have a working solution authenticating with the Google Custom Search Api, post April 20th 2015?

**Longer version:**

I am trying to use the Google Custom Search Api to request on-demand indexing.
Before I even get started I am running into issues with Authentication.
According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api#auth) you should use the ClientLogin Api to authenticate.
This Api was closed down on April 20th 2015, and it now returns 404 when you try and get a token from it.

The deprecation notice on the ClientLogin [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps) states to use Oauth instead.

I have therefore tried to authenticate pretty much the same as Hossein [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31462940/379521)
I am receiving a bearer token from Google, but when I try to make a request I get a 401 with the following message

```
<Error>You are not authorized to access this resource.  If you feel this is an error, try re-logging into your Google Account.</Error>
```

This is no real surprise, since there is no uptodate documentation and I am blindly stumbling along trying to find a correct solution.

**My current code in C#:**

```c#
private static async Task Run()
{
    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential( new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("blablabla@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
    {
        Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cse" }
    }.FromPrivateKey("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"));
    await credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    var token = credential.Token;
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
    var content =
        new StringContent(
            @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><OnDemandIndex><Pages><Page url=""http://url.com/to/be/indexed"" /></Pages></OnDemandIndex>");
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
    var result = await client.PostAsync("http://www.google.com/cse/api/{user_id}/index/{CSE_Id}", content);
    var resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
}
```

Does anyone have a solution running that works up against the `www.google.com/cse/api/...` endpoints?

Any language would be useful, just to know that it actually does work.